# Is possible in trigger insert to move the row to another table if condition?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to move a row when inserting if one condition.

With a "before insert trigger" I can copy the file to another table, but I cannot delete the original one.
If I throw an exception it'll rolback the insert in the secon table.

This is a MariaDB database and I have no access to the code, so I need to edit this in database.
I have tested a Before or after in insert trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `DisableByAccuracy` AFTER INSERT ON `tc_positions` FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.accuracy >= 500 THEN
        BEGIN
            SET NEW.valid = 0;
            INSERT INTO tc_positions_invalid (id, valid, latitude, longitude, accuracy) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.valid, NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude, NEW.accuracy);
            DELETE FROM tc_positions WHERE tc_positions.id = NEW.id;
        END;
END IF
```

I expect to move the row to invalid table if it's trying to write a row with and accuracy greater than 500.

Comment: You can't modify the table you have triggered on. If your tc_positions_invalid isn't transactional (i.e. MyISAM) what happens?

Comment: thx @danblack, any workaround? can I thow an exception with the row, cacth it and write in the invalid data table?

Comment: I provided a solution where a signal may be thrown for testing. I generally don't like working under 'no access to code' so the suggestion is as far as I'm going.